# Template deduction / type convertion error

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I am having trouble with template deduction / type conversion. The following code fails to compile:

```
template <typename Type>
struct A
{
    void DoA()
    {
    }
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
    void DoB()
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &p)
{
    p->DoA();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> pb(new B);
    DoSmth(pb);

    //std::shared_ptr<A<B>> pa(pb);
    //DoSmth(pa);
    return 0;
};
```

MSVC error is as follows:

```
error C2664: 'void DoSmth<B>(const std::shared_ptr<A<B>> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<B>' to 'const std::shared_ptr<A<B>> &'
Binding to reference with added qualification
followed by
Call to constructor 'std::shared_ptr<A<B>>::shared_ptr<B,void>(const std::shared_ptr<B> &) throw()'
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(531) : see declaration of 'std::shared_ptr<A<B>>::shared_ptr'
followed by
Binding to reference
```

GCC error:

```
prog.cpp:28:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘DoSmth(std::shared_ptr<B>&)’
  DoSmth(pb);
           ^
prog.cpp:21:6: note: candidate: template<class T> void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<A<T> >&)
 void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &p)
      ^~~~~~
prog.cpp:21:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:28:11: note:   mismatched types ‘A<T>’ and ‘B’
  DoSmth(pb);
           ^
```

The problem doesn't happen with the commented code (when the conversion is done by hand) nor does it happen if `i_a` is not a template class. I wonder why the compiler cannot make the conversion if (according to error message) it already has deduced template type (that way it should be equivalent to the commented code).

Is there something I can do about this without changing the function's argument type (I desperately need it to be `A<T>`)? Please note that `shared_ptr` class is used just to illustrate the problem, I actually use another smart pointer class, which I can change easily (in case if changes need to be done there).

Please also note that if raw pointers are used instead of smart ones, everything works like a charm!

Comment: why would it know you need a `DoSmth<B>`? Maybe you B can inherit from `A<B>` and `A<C>`, than what would you expect it to produce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that in `void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<A<T>> &p)` `T` is a dependent type and cannot be deduced.  So we need to give the compiler some help.  Thankfully we can use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to constrain the template.  If we use

```
template <typename T>
void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<T> &p)
```

Then `T` is now deducible but this function will accept any shared pointer which is not what we want.  We only want a `T` that is a `A<T>` or something the is derived from it.  Using `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of` we can do that like

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A<T>, T>::value>::type>
void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<T> &p)
{
    p->DoA();
}
```

And now we can pass a `std::shared_ptr<B>` to the function without having to do anything extra.  Here is an example showing it working and also it rejecting a `shared_ptr` of a non derived type:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <typename Type>
struct A
{
    void DoA()
    {
    }
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
    void DoB()
    {
    }
};

struct Foo {};

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A<T>, T>::value>::type>
void DoSmth(const std::shared_ptr<T> &p)
{
    p->DoA();
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> pb(new B);
    DoSmth(pb); // this compiles
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pf(new Foo);
    DoSmth(pf); // this will generate a compiler error

    //std::shared_ptr<A<B>> pa(pb);
    //DoSmth(pa);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29a13e6b64cec66a)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using `enable_if`, but I thought that there might be some other way.
The strange thing here is that according to error message, the compiler (at least MSVC) has deduced the required type, but couldn't make the convertion.

Comment: actually, I was a bit wrong - I also need `DoSmth(pf);` to compile, BUT to compile a different specialization of template

Comment: @ArtyomChirkov You might need to ask a new question then an detail what you have and what you would like.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly give the type.

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> pb(new B);
    DoSmth<B>(pb);
    //-----^
}
```

Comment: That is also not an option